# GitHub Pages trailing slashes

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, middleman

Using Middleman on GitHub Pages with [directory_indexes](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/pretty_urls/) enabled, I wonder if I can somehow get rid of the trailing slash GitHub adds.

My urls are basically: `/foo-bar -> /foo-bar/index.html`.

Visiting `/foo-bar` on GitHub Pages redirects to `/foo-bar/`.

Is there any way to prevent this redirect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A "trailing slash" redirect is issued when the server receives a request for a
>   URL http://servername/foo/dirname where dirname is a directory. Directories
>   require a trailing slash, so mod_dir issues a redirect to
>   http://servername/foo/dirname/.

[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html)

The problem with this is that GitHub pages / Jekyll build the way you have shown
above. To fix this, `foo-bar` needs to be a file rather than a directory:

```
http://example.com/foo-bar.html
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
http://example.com/foo-bar
```

[§ Permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks)

Comment: The problem is that the Middleman dev server doesn't find files without the html extension, so I have to use directories. I guess I just have to live with trailing slashes.